FDR in a gene expression experiment with two similar treatments
Given is the following experiment. Gene expression profiles across thousands of genes are obtained for three conditions: two drugs (= treatments) with a similar phenotypic effect and a control group. Each condition is replicated. A differential gene expression test (Wald or likelihood-ratio test) is performed for each gene and each of the two treatment-control groups. The purpose is to compare the drugs: to obtain a list of genes responding to both drugs and to each one of them individually.
Intuitively, two genes with the same p-value in one treatment but different p-values in the other treatment should be weighted differently. The idea is to leverage the fact that many of the genes will respond to both drugs simultaneously. What would be the right approach to combining the p-values for the same gene, controlling the FDR and binning the genes into those responding to both drugs and responding to only one drug?
EDIT
I accept the fuzziness of the treatment-specific group (which is my takeaway from the concerns raised in the responses), so I'd like to narrow down the question to the "shared" genes: Given two similar treatments and a shared control group, find the genes for which there is evidence of effect from both treatments under a specific FDR cutoff.
As has been discussed, one approach is to simply apply an FDR cutoff to the two vectors of p-values for the two treatments separately. This is not designed for joint hypothesis testing and will discard true discoveries. One workaround might be to apply a relaxed FDR cutoff but this still does not give a control over the FDR of the final gene set.
Another approach is outlined here: https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0063290 - using Stouffer's test (unweighted z-test) which the authors claim to behave satisfactory even under the condition of dependency (shared control group). I do not see this approach widely utilized in literature. My understanding is that weighted z-test is would perform better if the effect sizes are different (which is the case with treatment1 and treatment2).
EDIT2
How about a likelihood-ratio test approach in which I would first test for the effect of the full model: ~ treatment1 + treatment2 (where treatment1 and treatment2 are binary factors) against ~1 and for those genes which pass the FDR threshold, explore the contribution of the two treatment terms by comparing the full model to the reduced single-treatment models (~ treatment1 and ~ treatment2) and checking the LFCs for the two treatments? I'm not sure how (and even whether) to adjust the results of the second test: on some level, I'm exploring the contribution of the terms for models which have already been selected.

Cross-posted on bioconductor: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/9159081

"Intuitively, two genes with the same p-value in one treatment but different p-values in the other treatment should be weighted differently. The idea is to leverage the fact that many of the genes will respond to both drugs simultaneously." You may have this intuition, but could you more formally explain this to statisticians. What sort of null hypothesis are you testing and what sort of alternative hypothesis would you like to have a large power? What sort of research question is to be answered by the test that you wish to perform?

"Gene expression profiles across thousands of genes are obtained for three conditions" Do you have repetitions? Do you consider certain types of distributions? What sort of variables are these expressions (non-negative without limit, or something between 0 and 1)? Etc.?

Why first compute two p-values and then make decisions based on two p-values? This is a loss of information and not well motivated. (possibly similar to analysing a combination of seperate ANOVA tests instead of performing a MANOVA).

@SextusEmpiricus Pls see my answer below

That answer can not be understood without better explaining your question. What sort of experiment did you do exactly and what research question is your experiment about? Currently you only explain "A test is performed for each gene and each of the two treatment-control groups" and that can mean all sorts of things, how you did that  and where the data comes from (the basis for statistical modelling) is left out and you jump towards the end with questions about weighing and FDR, which is difficult to judge.

I have added more details to the question.

p-values can he combined in all sorts of different ways (an example here When combining p-values, why not just averaging?. There is no single best method. Why choose one over the other, that's difficult to say without knowing what it is about.

"Each condition is replicated." what sort of replication and how many? Also, are there paired treatments?

"A differential gene expression test (Wald or likelihood-ratio test) is performed for each gene and each of the two treatment-control groups." What sort likelihood is assumed? What sort of Wald test is performed (e.g. you make a MLE first, how and based on what variable/observation?).

As I mention in the EDITs and in my answer - the approach that has been implemented exactly for this type of design is the two-stage procedure.

The 'two-stage' procedure doesn't clarify the data generating process and the research question. It is impossible to answer how p-values should be combined.

@SextusEmpiricus The replicates are not paired. Otherwise the question is formulated in intentionally broad terms.

@SextusEmpiricus I understand that it would sound condescending but the question (in its strict formulation as in my EDIT) belongs to a specific class of problems discussed e.g. in literature on gene-expression data and meta-analysis of thereof. This is a stereotypical gene expression experiment with a simple ~ condition design and one shared control group for two treatments. It's not about my data and the exact tests I do even if my answer does mention specific packages that can be used here.

That may be true, but it doesn't change that the answer is formulated too broad and without much information to allow others to speak properly of ways/suggestions to combine the p-values. Combining p-values can be done in various ways and the question doesn't provide a background that helps to tackle a selection. It is even more condenscending that you come with your own self-accepted answer explaining the 'most natural way' and disqualify other answers which come with decent arguments against your approach, but do not have the possibility to know what your ideas are about a good answer.

"The idea is to leverage the fact that many of the genes will respond to both drugs simultaneously. What would be the right approach to combining the p-values for the same gene," This part is completely unexplained and unmotivated. The 'right approach' doesn't exist without clear goals.

@SextusEmpiricus I think there is no point in continuing this discussion. I'm asking to delete the question, my apologies to all of the contributors.

I'm not too happy about doing these set operations on tables of gene expression (or equivalent tables) as they require arbitrary thresholds applied to continuous measures. But anyway...
You have a table for "control vs drug A" and a table for "control vs drug B".
Genes with evidence of responding to both drugs would be those with fdr < 0.05 (or whatever cutoff) in both tables. Perhaps you may want to apply a cutoff also to the absolute fold-change to disregard genes changing only minimally but significantly (that's one of the murky aspects of this exercise).
Next, instead of looking for genes responding to one drug only it may be statistically and biologically more sensible to ask for genes responding differently between drug A and B. Depending on the experimental design it may be a simple contrast "A vs B" or "(control - drug A) - (control - drug B)".

From comment:

a relaxed [fdr] specifically for the purpose of finding genes responding to both A and B and a more stringent one for binning the rest of the genes as non-responding, responding to A and responding to B.

I think that's ok, but if at all possible I would try to avoid binning genes into responding/non-responding since bins don't have a neat biological basis. Since genes work in a network, every gene is going to be differentially expressed. You just need a sample size large enough to detect it. For this reason I find shrunk logFC easier to work with and more interpretable (but see this criticism from @GordonSmyth).

Thanks for your response! Applying FDR separately for the two sets of p-values is exactly what I want to avoid. I would like to first combine the evidence from the two treatments and then control the FDR. About the "A vs B" contrast: for this particular analysis it would be not informative as one of the treatments can (and does) elicit a stronger response (higher LFCs).

I was thinking more in the direction of a meta-analysis with a shared control group in the spirit of this approach: https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0063290.

An approach which would still involve independent control of FDR for each treatment might be to apply two FDR cutoffs: a relaxed one specifically for the purpose of finding genes responding to both A and B and a more stringent one for binning the rest of the genes as non-responding, responding to A and responding to B. What do you think?

@alephreish see edit to my answer

"every gene is going to be differentially expressed" This might be correct on some level but 1) the reasonable assumption for DGE analyses is that most of the genes are not differentially expressed; 2) what interests most ppl is the major players which such bins approximate; 3) an additional cutoff on LFC is of course the right thing to do although p-values should capture this as well (in reality this obviously does not always happen).

One should also be careful with LFC thresholds: if for a low-LFC gene the counts are well-behaved (high enough and without outliers) and within-treatment variance is low leading to a low p-value, it might simply mean that the response is restricted e.g. to a particular tissue/sub-population.

As a biologist, I agree with @dariober (+1) that your "binning the genes into those responding to both drugs and responding to only one drug" isn't such a good idea. I see experiments with FDR control as providing guides to future detailed investigation rather than definitive answers about what's "significant." You're presumably going to have to report results for all the genes in supplemental data for your publication anyway, so you can let your readers do whatever binning they might find useful. Were I to read your paper I would want to see the results for each drug individually against control, even if you choose to combine results between the drugs in some way.
What you want to do seems very similar to what's described in Section 5.4, "Control versus the rest," of the Bioconductor vignette on design matrices. Briefly, once the design matrix for the experiment is set up and analysis performed with limma or a similar workflow, you can set up contrasts on the modeled coefficients of the genes to compare, for example, the average of both treatments against control.
In your case, if you know that one drug systematically leads to greater log fold changes (LFC) in expression than the other, you could use a weighted average of the drug-treatment expression values instead. For example, if one drug typically leads to only 2/3 the log fold changes seen with the other drug, you could multiply its coefficients by 1.5 to put both drugs on similar scales (then divide by 2.5 to put the sums of the weighted values on the same scale as the control).
That will provide comparisons that directly respect and work with the (moderated) error estimates for all gene-expression values, for control and both drugs. You then use the results of that weighted comparison to document (with a function like topTable() in limma) the corresponding (weighted) LFCs, p-values, FDRs, etc. to identify genes that might "respond to both drugs" based on this weighted average between the drugs.
With all the data from the same experiment, that should be more reliable than trying to combine things like p-values or F-statistics, as you might need to do in a meta-analysis.
In response to comments and edited question
I think that you are putting too much emphasis on FDR as a strict criterion. Benjamini-Hochberg FDR control assumes independence among tests, which probably isn't the case with gene-expression studies when multiple genes in the same pathway are likely to be affected. I thus think of FDR as a guide rather than a cutoff.
You are correct that using (weighted) averaging for the FDR might identify a gene with a very large response to one treatment but none to the other. You would presumably, however, plot the response to one treatment against the response to the other for all the genes that pass the averaged FDR criterion, to identify such genes with highly differential responses.
If you want instead to use an overlap of the genes affected by the treatments individually, I'd suggest that you identify the same number of differentially expressed genes from the treatments, then look for overlap between those two sets. That's consistent with the recommendations of the "Overlap of treatment-control results" section of the design-matrix vignette (which discusses varying "significance" thresholds) and functionally equivalent to your suggestion of relaxing the FDR for the drug with the lower overall responses. I think that choosing a common number of genes will be easier to explain to your audience than how you chose a particular relaxed FDR.
Nothing prevents you from using both methods to document the agreement (and thus the presumed reliability, given the gene-expression data) of the two gene-identification approaches.
Whether you use the FDR on a weighted average or the overlap method, you run the risk of missing "true discoveries" of genes that just happened to have high variance in responses during this experiment. And, of course, any attempt to "minimiz[e] rejection of true discoveries" will tend to increase the identifcation of false discoveries.

Thanks! I do see that the "treatment-specific" bins are problematic, so let's set them aside, this is not the point of the question. The essence of the question is about minimizing rejection of true discoveries for the genes for which there is evidence of effect from both treatments.

In the limma vignette, my case is described in "Overlap of treatment-control results" where it is suggested to apply separate FDR cutoffs which is my current strategy (see my comment to dariober's question above about making it more flexible).

Correct me if I'm wrong but the averaging approach might but is not guaranteed to bring genes which respond to both treatments.

@alephreish I added a bit to this answer. I suggest that you think of FDR control as a guide rather than a strict cutoff. That's essentially what you would be doing with the separate FDR cutoffs, anyway. If you explain how you analyzed the data, provide a reasonable explanation for your approach, and make the data available to others (as is now commonly required) so that they can try other approaches, you should be OK. If you try different approaches yourself and they agree for most genes, that would strengthen your argument.

Thanks a lot for your contribution but I think you misunderstand the question. It's about the proper approach to hypothesis testing. The approach that specifically tests for the kind of hypotheses I'm interested in is called two-stage testing procedure and allows to control the OFDR (overall FDR) - I discovered it after writing my "EDIT2" but it follows the the same logic (the remaining issue boils down to how to properly adjust the p-values for the second stage) - I'll post an answer later.

Thanks again for your edited response, there are more thought-provoking ideas in it than I originally appreciated. I feel that the OFDR approach is still overly conservative - this is not the exact kind of FDR I want to control. I accept the general criticism of focusing on FDRs but I'm really after a framework that would allow for the specific type of hypothesis testing. Meta-analysis and two-stage analysis are the two approaches that come close to this.

While all of the listed solutions in my first EDIT are valid at least on some level, the most natural way of approaching the problem of revealing the genes responding to both treatments with a full control over the FDR (in this case: the overall FDR or OFDR) is the stage-wise method AKA the two-stage testing procedure which was introduced by Heller et al (2009) "A flexible two-stage procedure for identifying gene sets that are differentially expressed" and extended in the stageR package, Van den Berge et al (2017) "stageR: a general stage-wise method for controlling the gene-level false discovery rate in differential expression and differential transcript usage".
Briefly, when applied to the task at hand the procedure works as follows:

The screening stage consists of of testing the general effect of the condition for each gene. I do this with the likelihood-ratio test as implemented in DESeq2: the full model ~ treatment1 + treatment2 is tested against the intercept-only reduced model ~ 1.
Genes passing the screening stage with an FDR threshold are taken to the confirmation stage. Here I use LRT to test for the contribution of the individual terms (treatment1 and treatment2) to the full model. The p-values are FWER-adjusted per gene.

The design at hand allows to apply the modified sequentially rejective Bonferroni (MSRB) procedure, see Shaffer (1986) "Modified sequentially rejective multiple test procedures.": stageWiseAdjustment(method="none") in stageR. For details see the stageR vignette and the paper for details.
On top of the OFDR control, I add an additional filter on the minimal log-fold changes.


I think this two-stage framework is in the right direction but the OFDR approach still seems overly restrictive when it comes to finding the DE genes shared by two treatments due to the FDR adjustment on the second stage. This procedure treats all of the confirmation hypotheses together disregarding the fact that the structure of the data.
